# How to for loop in Math like C?

Tags: programming

In C, we can for loop easily. But I don't know how we can loop in Math like C.

For example, I want to loop in Math like this C code:

```
int i;
int a = 10;
for (i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
    a -= 2;
}
```

Comment: It’s a(100)$^{99}$.

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything.

Comment: Mathematics has things like recurrences $a_n=a_{n-1}-1$ and sums $\sum\limits_{i=i}^{99} 100i$ and products $\prod\limits_{i=i}^{99} 100i$

Comment: I'm really sorry, I edited my code.

Comment: Math is not a programming language.

Comment: @user3733558 Yes. But I don't want to program in Math. I want to find equivalent of my code in Math.

Comment: You can't establish equivalence relationships for objects or structures that don't belong to the same category. If you were talking about a functional programming language like Haskell, you may have had a chance (even so, I'm doubtful you can always do it), but certainly not with C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, we don't need to loop in mathematics, because we have alternative constructs.

Two examples, the first one is probably the best translation of yours:

$u_0 = 10, u_{n+1} = u_n - 2$, an arithmetic sequence, of which you're asking the 99-th value ($u_{99}$).

But often, you'll want to have an operation like the functional programming "fold/reduce"; which acts like a for-loop over an array, for a given operator.

For this, we have the "indexed $n$-ary operators", also called "generalized operators".

For addition:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} a^i = a^1 + a^2 + \dots + a^n$$

For multiplication:

$$\prod_{i=0}^{i=n} i+4 = 4 \times 5 \times \dots \times (n + 4)$$

You can also define an $n$-ary version for basically every binary operator you can find: $\bigcup$, $\bigcap$, etc.

The rest of the syntax consists in picking your indices intelligently. Say you wanted to sum over all elements of a matrix (generally done with a nested for-loop with $i$ and $j$ iterators), you could define it as something like this:

$$\sum_{i=1, j=1}^{i=n, j=m} a_{ij}$$

Comment: You probably mean $\prod_{i=0}^{i=n} i+4 = (0+4)(1+4)\dots (n + 4)$.

Comment: Yes thanks, I'll edit my answer to fix it

Answer (score -1):

Let $a_i$ be the value of the variable `a` after the $i$-iteration, then
$$a_0 = 10, \qquad a_{i+1} = a_i - 2$$

One could show by induction that
$$a_i = 10-2i$$
for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$.